# Why doesn't shell_exec of php work with here?

Tags: c#, php, command-line, console, shell-exec

I have a php script and an exe file created using c#. I want php to execute that exe file. I tried to use `shell_exec` command. But nothing is happening!! Then I tried echo `shell_exec("dir");` and it works by displaying the info.

Why is it not executing the exe file. Few months back I have used it and it worked fine on xpdf, brc and opera.

I tried giving absolute path, I tried adding to path variable. But its not working. *Interesting thing is that my exe file executes perfectly from command Line*. I think something is wrong with php.

I am using Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6

PHP Script:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("Face_Trainer.exe");
?>
```

C# exe file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Face_Trainer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Beep();

        }
    }
}
```

I need this shell_exec to work to complete my project, everything else is fine, just this function!

Comment: What does `Face_Trainer.php` have to do with a `C#` file?

Comment: @MartinKonecny it was a typo...sorry.because script was small i just typed it. its Face_Trainer.exe

Comment: When you run the .exe by itself (i.e. from windows explorer) does it beep?

Comment: @WaiHaLee Yes it beeps. it beeps even through cmd because I hav added its path to path variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution:

You are using a non interactive shell, that is why you don't hear a beep. You can check it with writing a file, if a file is created your program runs fine in your current setup.

---

Other remarks:

If you really try to execute an exe file you should use the right extension:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("Face_Trainer.exe");
?>
```

Since that seems to be an typo, here comes another hint: I would run a batch file where you setup your environment for your application. Here an example:

```
@echo off
set path=%path%;x:\your\path
cd x:\dir\of\exe
Face_Trainer.exe
```

Comment: I tried that. I set path and executed it from normall command line, as >Face_Trainer.exe and it beepd. Then I created a batch file and while double clicking bat file it beeped but through php, it just echo the location of bat file and command in it, i mean location/of/bat/Face_Trainer.exe

Comment: I think php or apache is corrupted...when i echo shell_exec("path"); its showing old path. I am trying to reinstall. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Just thinking do you really want to let your computer beep or is this just a test? If it is a test try something different like writing a file. I coould imagine that the beep command doesn't work on a non interactive shell.

Comment: No you got me wrong instead of executing your exe file you should only execute my bat file from my answer. If you set the path within a exec call the changes will only apply that php line and not the next call.

Comment: its a test to get started...actually its a face recogonition software's face training module. I just want to start the module after php copies the images from upload dir, so shell exec

Comment: the problem was non-interactive shell!! I tried writing a file as you said and the file was successfully created, but only in the dir where the php script was. But i just want to update databases and now it works..Thanks for your invaluable suggesstion.If you could write it as an answer, then i could mark it...Thanks a lot friend!